# Changing parent page's title from user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a newbie to asp.net. I have an asp.net page which uses a user control. 
On Page_Load event of this control, I want to change the title of the parent aspx page.
I need help on this please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try create a property in usercontrol and next call this property using your instance of usercontrol in page like

In UserControl

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyProperty = "This is a test";
    }

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

`
In Page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebUserControl11.PreRender += new EventHandler(WebUserControl11_PreRender);
    }

    void WebUserControl11_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = WebUserControl11.MyProperty;
        this.Header.Title = str;
    }
```

Comment: Just a hair complicated, don't you think? :)

Comment: Maybe yes, but remember this guy need get text from a property in usercontrol, maybe another solution work, but this is my solution.

Answer (score 10):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "New Title";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set this in your USERCONTROL:

```
this.Page.Master.Page.Header.Title = "text text title title";
```